# How to change default username of postgres (not rename username postgres to something) in windows

Tags: postgresql

When I login to postgres in Windows cmd using `psql` command it by default tries to login to the user name `ADMIN` which is my windows user account name, and such user name actually does not exist in the database, I know how to change that by `-U` attribute like this `psql -U postgres`. I want to login with user name `postgres` by default without specifying in the command prompt. like changing any configuration files etc. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That thread suggests by setting an environment variable:

https://superuser.com/questions/1278748/postgresql-on-windows-psql-expects-me-to-log-in-with-my-windows-account

> The PGUSER environment variable is considered when the -U option is
> not set.
>
> So you may use a batch file essentially doing:

```
set PGUSER=postgres
psql
```